# Availability of older sample code for iPhone 2.2

Tags: iphone

We've been programming an iPhone application under iPhone OS 3.1, but the client has now decided he wants us to redo the existing codebase to run under 2.2. One of the nice pieces of built-in functionality we used under 3.1 was the `UISearchDisplayController` functionality for searching UITableViews, but that functionality was not available previously and I'm not sure how to create the equivalent code under 2.2 from scratch.

Long story short, does anyone know where I can obtain earlier sample code? The `TableSearch` example apparently existed under 2.2 and would likely be very useful to me, but I don't know how to obtain it. When I go to look online at the available Apple sample code, I'm redirected to the latest 3.1 versions, which don't do me any good.

Howard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't have any luck tracking down that sample code either. You could try the wayback machine though.

Btw, just to give you some stats to take to your client.  Currently > 75% of iPhone OS users are on 3.0 or better according to 3rd party sources.  Writing code for <25% (and decreasing) of a market is generally not a good idea.  It sticks you with code that is harder to maintain and test, etc., etc.  I'm sure you know all this.  Anyway, you should really see if you can convince them to drop 2.2.1 support.